# Code is not readable in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Please assist, how do I remove this on my code to be visible (highlighted in yellow)[remove the code highlighted in gray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F1KN.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2015 (and most probably other versions), you can find color options for Razor in Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors. Check the following image for details:

[image: Environment color]